# jupgrade extension is not working in my site

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I am trying to upgrade my joomla website which is 1.5.26 to version 2.5 through jupgrade but it's not working properly. Jupgrade is not working properly and nothing has bee doing or happened in jupgrade. I've readed in many forums that it's due to mootools plugin problem. I've downloaded and installed the latest version of mootools plugin in my website but still it's not working and also still not working. i really don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me for fixing it.

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: No error(Nothing). In fact, i've enabled the debugging mode also but still it's not showing any kinds of error!

Comment: what happen when you click on upgrade link in com_jupgrade ?

Comment: Whenever i press that jupgrade button then it's not doing anything except pressing down!

Answer (score 1):

First you uninstall the `jupgrade` then remove the tables **if created** `jupgrade_categories`, `jupgrade_menus` , `jupgrade_modules`, `jupgrade_steps`. Also remove all the tables created by new joomla, then **clear the cache** and **restart** your server and install the `jupgrade` plugin. Click on setting button in jupgrade then set

Skip checks - yes, Enable migration debug - yes, Enable `Mootools` version debug - yes

Then start upgrading......

or

jUpgrade is rather notorious for having all kinds of glitches and problems.

One easy, simple way to get past a downloading problem is to download the version of Joomla you want directly from Joomla's site, extract it into jUpgrade's target folder for your soon-to-be-migrated site, and then change jUpgrade's settings to skip the download process:

This works for me.I think this will work...

Comment: have you enable curl in you php.ini file.

Comment: Now it has started working as i disabled rest of the plugins but now it's been stucked on downloading part, any ideas?

Comment: Not a fault in the component, you probably lost internet connection for a bit or there was a server glicth. Just try again and it wil most likely work

Comment: Hmm, so i have to start it again?

Comment: Ya try it again and change settings and restart your server every time if change any settings.

Comment: HMm okays,if i get stucked at any point then i will post it here..:) Thanks for your help:))

Comment: I noticed this happens sometimes when some plugins conflict, e.g. rokbox and similar. try disabling some more unessential plugins in the plugin manager - you can always turn them back on later.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @Trev. I also got same problem & solved by disabling some plugin. You can check in console to get what exactly conflicting. I'm sure it must be problem with Jquery conflict. BTW Jupgrate is very good & amazing part is its completely free & quick responsive.

Comment: I've disabled all the plugins except mootools but still it's get stucked in the same step. I also removed ; from curl in php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution for me!
As for you nothing worked.
So i turned on my brain, and started thinking.
Firebug was saying: "options not defined", jupgrade javascript was broken.
Then i searched in joomla plugin directory and i cannot find any mtupgrade dir nor mtupgrade.php,
but the plugin was listed and activated.
So i took a full version of Joomla 1.5.26, which is the version i was upgrading,
entered plugin/system dir, copied mtupgrade dir into my Joomla 1.5.26 plugin/system installation,
than copied mtupgrade.php in plugin/system, not in mtupgrade dir.
Went to jUpgrade and worked like a charm!
Some issues:
Download or jUpgrade can stuck while they are working. If this happens... 2 solutions.
1. Download Joomla 2.5 and unzip in new /jupgrade folder, you have to create.
2. Let jUpgrade download Joomla 2.5 and when block, go to setting, click "Skip Download", and reload jUpgrade plugin. I did like this, and worked like a charm.

I hope i helped you.

Marco.